Needed Assistance - EMI Issues with 16x2 LCD Display (Model BCB-1602-03C)
Hello stack Exchange Community,
I am Yogesh D from Trident Pneumatics Private Limited, R&D Innovation - Electronics. We are currently using a 16x2 LCD display (model BCB-1602-03C) in the controllers (parallel connection) of our dryers. However, we are encountering significant EMI issues that are affecting the display's performance.
The specific issues we are facing include:

Distortion of characters on the display
Discoloration and character mismatch

We are using the PIC 16F 876A - E/S P microcontroller in our circuit. I have attached the schematic diagram of our current setup for reference.

We would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions from the community on how to resolve these EMI issues.
We would be very thankful if any of you resolve the issue and give the altered schematic diagram.
If anyone has encountered similar problems or has experience with EMI mitigation for LCD displays, your insights would be invaluable.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Welcome! What does your layout look like?

Welcome -- EMC is a deep and complex topic; often, there isn't much to see from a schematic alone. What of the PCB layout, cable construction, assembly drawings, etc. can you share about this project?

It has been my experience, unless we're talking radio transmitters, it is better to mitigate EMI noise at the source. That means putting noise suppression hardware on motors, relays, solenoids and just about anything that can draw large amounts of current.

I would run tests in an attempt to isolate the issue. Run the PIC/LCD from a separate power source. Shield the PIC/LCD with Mu Metal. Etc.
